# Is the logit model with simulated data set up correctly?

Tags: r, logistic, generalized-linear-model

Good day,

is the logit model with simulated data set up correctly? I think it isn't because the model fit is poor and the estimated coefficients don't match the ones I set up. How could the fit be improved? As I set up a binomial model earlier, the fit was very good, but now when the Xs have a dependance structure and more than two variables, for some reason is the glm-logit model not estimating the coefficients properly. I believe the reason is, because my data generating process is faulty, supposedly the calculation of the logit probabilities. Or maybe the signal to noise ratio is too small.

Update: I changed the betas to 2 and the McFadden-Score improved significantly.

Thanks

```
n=100     #number of observations
p=3       #number of variables
beta1=0.5 #coeffcients
beta2=0.5
beta3=0.5
mu=rep(0,p)
covar=toeplitz(0.5^(0:(p-1))) 
X=rmvnorm(n=n, mean=mu, sigma=covar)
library(extRemes)                   
e = revd(n,loc=0,scale=1,shape=1) #does the structure of e need to match the structure of x?

z=X*beta1+X*beta2+X*beta3+e
#Calculation of denominator for probability calculation
Denominator= 1+exp(-z[,2])+exp(-z[,3])            #beta1 is the reference category, therefore left out
#Calculating the matrix of probabilities for three choices
pr = cbind(1/Denominator, exp(-z[,2])/Denominator, exp(-z[,3])/Denominator )
#pr <- 1/(1 + exp(-z))
Y = rbinom(n,1,pr)

# fit Logit model
logit<- glm(Y ~ X, family=binomial (link = "logit"))
summary(logit) 

# McFadden's Pseudo R-squared
logit0<-update(logit, formula= Y ~ 1)
McFadden<- 1-as.vector(logLik(logit)/logLik(logit0))
McFadden
```

Comment: I don't really understand the step where you got `pr`. Why not just use `pr <- 1/(1 + exp(-z))` as you wrote but commented out? Also, the problem might be `e`. Currently it's an omitted variable (not in the fit model) but in the generated model. The coefficients change depending on which variables are in the model, even if they are independent from each other (as `e` is from the `X`s). See [here](doi.org/10.1146/annurev-soc-073117-041429) for discussion of this.